# Can you Dispel a spell buff on a Rakshasa?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[Rakshasa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/rakshasa) have Limited Spell Immunity and can only be affected by spells of 6th level and lower if they want to be affected. Let's say I'm fighting a Rakshasa who is under the effects of a *Haste* spell. If I want to dispel the *haste* spell, presumably I cannot target the Rakshasa with *Dispel Magic*, but can I target the *Haste* effect?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

In order to end the [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell you would have to target the rakshasa.

From the description of [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic):

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

The *haste* spell isn't creating a magical effect in the space (that is things like illusions, walls of fire, etc.). If you would like to argue otherwise you are very quickly into the realm of things 5e doesn't define properly (ie. what is an object, magical effect, etc.?).

Do note that you can end it by casting *dispel magic* using a 7th level spell slot (or higher) which would automatically end all spells of 7th level or lower on it.

Comment: This begs the question though, is the Rakshasa affected by Dispel Magic or is the spell that is affecting the Rakshasa the one affected. Note that it doesn't say can't be targeted.

Comment: "that is things like illusions, walls of fire, etc" — is there any rule that defines magical effects this way? Or is it your interpretation of the word?

Comment: The checklist Wizards of the Coast provided to determine whether an effect is magical is: 1. Is it a magic item? 2. Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description? 3. Is it a spell attack? 4. Is it fueled by the use of spell slots? 5. Does its description say it’s magical? So the things *created* by spells count as magical effects for the purposes of Dispel Magic. In the case of Haste, the description only gives the bonuses to the target and doesn't say any kind of tangible thing is put into the world that Dispel Magic could target.

Comment: Your title is a hard "No", but your justification rambles into "thigns 5e doesn't define properly".  Your explanation does not support your thesis.